# Keep getting HTML1527 in IE & Edge when downloading a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, microsoft-edge

So I have a html canvas which the user can download by clicking a link. It works fine on chrome but on internet explorer and the new MS Edge I can getting a HTML 1527 Warning and it doesn't download anything just crashes..

**Here is my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0       Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="364.8" height="220.8" style=" border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

<script>
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.innerHTML = 'download image';
    link.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
        link.download = "mypainting.png";
    }, false);
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        context.font = "20pt Tahoma";
        context.fillStyle = '#3a3a3a';
        context.fillText("Test2", 20, 100);
        context.font = "15pt Tahoma";
        context.fillStyle = '#3a3a3a';
        context.fillText("Test2", 20, 130);
    };
    imageObj.src = "T1.png"; 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the `DOCTYPE` to a valid one?

Comment: Yes I have tried different DOCTYPES but it doesn't change anything @dave

Comment: Even `<!DOCTYPE html>`? The `.download` property is HTML 5 only, and your doctype as posted may be preventing HTML 5 functionality.

Comment: Yes @Jacob even that... its the first one I tried.

Comment: @KevinBoucher It's not a duplicate because I shouldn't act this way

Comment: @Jacob, XHTML 1 doctype can't prevent HTML5 functionality. HTML5 can even validate with XHTML 1 Strict doctype (in non-DTD-based validators like validator.w3.org/nu). Only doctypes that trigger Quirks mode can make new features not work in IE.

Comment: Can you clarify "just crashes?" Are you saying the whole browser process dies, that it doesn't begin the download, or an error is produced? I think the warning is unrelated according to what @IlyaStreltsyn says.